# Removing of hypen in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, i have a column having data's like **C-45RE**. In another column of the same spreadsheet, I need to display **C45RE**. In excel how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,99)
```

**In English**: Take the left part of my text in A1. Stop 1 character before the `-`. Then add the middle part of my text in A1. Start 1 character after the `-`. Get up to 99 characters.

Comment: FYI you can change `99` with `LEN(A1)` to make it work no matter how long the string is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUBSTITUTE function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",1)
```